# How to compute IFFT in MATLAB when the coefficient array is dependent on a parameter in physical space?

Tags: matlab, fft

First off, sorry for the poor math notation - there was no other way to properly describe the problem.

Let's say I have a variable u(x,y,z,t) that I have Fourier transformed (abstractly, at the very least) in x,z,t so that I have something like

u(x,y,z,t) = sum_{k_x,k_z,k_t} u'(k_x,k_z,k_t,y) e^(i(k_x x + k_z z - k_t t))

where the -k_t is a domain convention. Then, let's say there is a way for me to determine u'. I'd like to conduct an inverse Fourier Transform to return to the original, physical, space; in particular, I'd like this to be done at a fixed tuple of (k_x,k_z,k_t) so that effectively, the u' is just a function of y.

Beginning with a 1D array of the Fourier coefficients u', which vary solely in y, one immediate way I can see is by noting the fact that k_x,k_z,k_t are fixed so the IFT is as simple as ignoring the sum and explicitly computing

u'(k_x, k_z,k_t,y)*e^(i(k_x x + k_z z - k_t t))

which gives me u(x,y,z,t) everywhere in my physical space-time domain. I have this coded up and it seems to work fine. I am mainly concerned with how this can be done instead with standard "built-in" algorithms, e.g. ifftn in MATLAB. Particularly, it seems these necessarily would conduct an IFT in y as well which is not what I want. I think I'd also have to pass in the Fourier coefficients as a 4D array, right? Apologies if this is a vague question...

**EDIT**: Let me try to add some more details.

I am beginning from a set of equations (specifically, the Navier Stokes equations), where all variables *could* depend on (x,y,z,t), where t is time. I then Fourier transform these equations in x,z as well as time and then discretize in y using a Chebyshev collocation method. This allows me to construct what's known as the resolvent operator (which is now discrete, of course) that I can conduct SVD on to gain access to the principal directions/modes at a particular wavenumber tuple. I would like to visualize these modes back in physical space, and as I understand, this requires an inverse Fourier transform. However, since the modes are, in principle, vectors (since they come from SVD), the data will necessarily be 1-D. Further, k_x, k_z, and k_t have already been assigned values e.g. k_x=k_z=k_t=1 while constructing the resolvent so the modes are essentially dependent on just y (though, yes, implicitly, they do depend on k_x, k_z, k_t). Additionally, in *physical space*, these should be functions of (x,y,z,t).

Comment: You could do `ifftn` on the 3D sub-arrays. If you have a 4D array, apply `ifft` to each of your three dimensions in turn.

Comment: Well, the background problem is formulated in a way that the coefficients vary only in y. In other words, the coefficient array I have is inherently 1D, and the values of k_x, k_z, and k_t are fixed from the start (so, essentially, it's not a sum of modes any more, I suppose). Is there a way to use ifftn on that 1D array directly to obtain a reconstruction in physical space, that is, in (x,y,z,t) of the original variable, u? Apologies for the confusing lingo...

Comment: That is indeed confusing. Maybe [edit] your post to add some example data (maybe generated with `randn` calls) to show us what your data actually looks like. This last comment makes me think you have a 1D array of y values, each has implicit associated x, z and t values? If so, you need to resample to a 3D array (see `griddata`) before you can apply `ifftn`.

Comment: OK, I added some data. Maybe it'd be helpful for me to state this: in physical space, the variable u depends on (x,y,z,t). But, in Fourier space, the coefficients depend on (k_x, y, k_z, k_t). In other words, we are only Fourier transforming in certain variables. After that, we fix (k_x, k_z, k_t) so that the coefficients are explicitly only dependent on y, which is why the coefficient input I have is in terms of a 1-D array.

Comment: I’m sorry, that’s just a bunch of numbers. I was hoping for a bit of code showing `k_x = […]; k_z = […];` and so on, so I can understand better what you’re talking about when you describe your problem. You have stuff that depends on 4 dimensions, but it’s only 1D data, because 3 dimensions are fixed? Isn’t it then just a 1D problem? If so, why talk about a 3D FFT?

Comment: OK, I did not add any code but I have added an expanded description of the problem; hopefully, that clarifies something... Note that I have already mentioned one way that I know this works in the original post. The only issue is that this is a bit more "manual" than just using a built-in IFT function in MATLAB.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but it sounds like you want to "hide" the `y` component from the Fourier transform routine. Looking at the docs `ifftn` doesn't seem to support this, but it says "_The N-D inverse transform is equivalent to computing the 1-D inverse transform along each dimension_" (which is fair enough), and `ifft` has a `dim` parameter that can be used to specify the axis along which you transform. So you can probably cherrypick the axes you need to transform to and fro one by one, skipping the axis corresponding to `y`.